# Poker self-evaluation: let's get critical!

Tags: discussion, status-completed

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find a few questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

Comment: I think a larger problem than general question quality (we have several good ones), is traffic.  We just aren't seeing a lot of new questions coming in to the site.

Comment: I still think the lack of a dedicated hand-history converter like the [FlopTurnRiver.com](http://poker-tools.flopturnriver.com/Hand-Converter.php) one or the built in one at [2+2](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/1/two-plus-two/) is a biggap in this sites reach!

Comment: please open this question back up.

Comment: @Jon Why? It's two+ years old. This evaluation is long over. If you want to start a new discussion about the site's quality, just post a new [discussion] question here on meta.

Comment: Because its relevant, your not making it here and the reasons are here also. simple answer it wont hurt. You guys really need to modify the approach to this thing.

Comment: You had great examples here, and these guys here need to rethink things if this is to succeed. I think the Q&A format is great, I think the Poker Beta has gone badly, I think they need to kind of reboot. I do have a discussion here.

Answer (score 2):

[Why is 7c2d a semi-bluff?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/571/why-is-7c2d-a-semi-bluff)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this one is good in that it contains discussion of a strategy concept. There are certainly better questions (that are more about strategy and less about definitions), but this is the best fit of the three IMO

Answer (score 0):

[In Omaha, Is it allowed to only show two holecards at showdown when claiming the pot?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/566/is-it-allowed-to-win-in-omaha-while-showing-only-two-holecards)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Unlike the [555 one](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/a/114/22), this isn't quite a basic rules question. The answer is good in that it cites a good source and is clear. Still, not really likely to attractive the kind of strategy discussion we'd most like to have.

Answer (score -1):

[Why does 555 beat QQQ in this Doyle vs Elezra hand?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/573/why-555-wins-qqq-in-this-doyle-vs-elezra-game)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think this one would turn people off more than it turned them on. It completely lacks strategy and makes it look like the site is more for basic rules than for strategy. The answers are fine in that they are accurate, but I don't think that is enough to keep people interested...

Comment: @JeffreyBlake I agree. The question only alludes to a possible strategy discussion, but ends up just asking about game mechanics.

Comment: this site will need to address basic rules as well as strategy discussion.